# In HugSQL SQL, Chinese parameters are replaced with question marks

Tags: clojure, hugsql

在HugSQL SQL中的中文参数，被替换成了问号。
In HugSQL SQL, Chinese parameters are replaced with question marks.

```sql
-- :name save-message-1! :! :n
-- :doc creates a new message
INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, timestamp) 
VALUES ('姓名', '消息测试', '2022-03-21 04:19:56')
```

The query result in the database is as follows：

```
# id, name, message, timestamp
'1', '??', '???', '2022-03-21 04:19:56'
```

Comment: Your question doesn't have any relevant code. But given that you show the SQL query itself, seems like it's your DB that doesn't handle the encoding right.

Comment: What `file.encoding` are you running with? And if this is MySQL, are the tables `CHARSET=utf8mb4` ?

Comment: MySQL Schema Character Set is UTF8; MySQL Schema Character Set is UTF8; Only through HugSQL through the input Chinese will have problems.
Here is the SQL configuration code:
-- :name save-message-1! :! :n
-- :doc creates a new message
INSERT INTO guestbook (name, message, timestamp)
VALUES (N'姓名', N'消息测试', '2022-03-21 04:19:56')
-- :name get-messages :? :*
-- :doc selects all available messages
SELECT * FROM guestbook where name='中文'

Comment: Please don't put code into comments. Edit the question and add it there. You have not answered the question about `file.encoding`. Also what is the encoding of the files? Also is _writing_ to your DB OK or does the insert already create broken content in the DB?